# Custom helper. How to get URI from an action method name and controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I'm writing my own helper and it needs to get a path as a parameter. I can of course refer to it directly passing a string or using Url.Action(). But what if I want to generate fully qualified URI inside of my helper method using action, controller and route values?

It does look a little bit messy right now

```
 @Ajax.MyHelper(Url.Content("~/Admin/Administration/DeleteItem?Id=<#= Id #>"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the helper, you can call

```
new UrlHelper(ajax.ViewContext.RequestContext).Content(...)
```